# Getting an error with python aerich after correct command

Tags: python, ini, tortoise-orm, pyproject.toml

I have the problem with aerich configs:

I have the `app/database.py` file with the next content:

```
TORTOISE_ORM = {
    "connections": {"default": "postgres://..."},
    "apps": {
        "models": {
            "models": ["app.models", "aerich.models"],
            "default_connection": "default",
        },
    },
}
```

Also I have a python package with tortoise tables located in `app/models/...`.
I'm trying to create first migrations file, using the next commands:

1. `aerich init -t app.database.TORTOISE_ORM` and I'm getting data inside of my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.aerich]
tortoise_orm = "app.database.TORTOISE_ORM"
location = "./migrations"
src_folder = "./."
```

2. After it I'm trying to run `aerich init-db`, but I'm getting an error: `tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Module "app.models" not found`
   I tried a lot of different variants to change this configs but getting the same error. Version of aerich==^0.6.2

Does everybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The models variable in the dictionary should contain the module containing the Model for your database. As per your description, you have a models directory that contains files with the Model. For example, you have hello.py which contains model classes inside the models folder then you need to provide "app.models.hello" instead of just "app.models".

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you also asked this [question in the aerich Github repo](https://github.com/tortoise/aerich/issues/233). Gave an answer there, but I'll repeat it here for completeness.

Just ran into this `tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Module <x> not found` error myself. Using a debugger, I found out that the problem - at least in my case - was actually not that the module could not be found. The `ImportError` raised (which leads to the `ConfigurationError`) was in fact hinting towards a problem with circular imports. Weirdly enough I don't get this circular import problem when using the app itself (which runs the same imports), but I do get it when using aerich...

Long story short:

1. Solving circular imports might do the trick here.
2. Tortoise should choose a different error message (e.g. just use the `msg` from the `ImportError`) as "Module not found" might simply not be the actual problem.